# type casting void pointer and allocate memory

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have two structures:

```
typedef struct abc {
  unsigned int pref;
  unsigned int port;
  char *aRecordIp;
    int index;
    int count;
}abc_t;

typedef struct xyz {
        abc_t *ab;
        int index;
        int count;
}xyz_t;
```

and I would like to achieve the following

```
int Lookup (char *lookup,void *handle) {

*handle = (xyz_t *)malloc(sizeof(xyz_t *));
handle->ab = (abc_t *) malloc(sizeof(abc_t *));
//

}
```

I am trying to typecast void pointer to xyz_t basically.

Is this correct?

Comment: `handle` is a void pointer, and has no type information, it is only an address in memory, so calling `handle->ab` will not work.

Comment: I want to type cast it to xyz_t and access ab

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't just change `Lookup` to take a `xyz_t*` instead of a `void*`?

Comment: I have to question the sanity of what is being done here.  You're passing in a void* (generated from where?) to overwrite its memory with a new structure and then accessing it.  What is the point of this?

Comment: @cmbasnett and Dennis Meng : handle is passed from another stack and it is a void pointer, I thought I could typecast it and use it

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong on multiple counts:

1. You're trying to set a variable `handle->ab`, but `handle` is a `void *`, not a structure type pointer.
2. You need to show your call, but there's likely to be problems — why do you think a `void *` argument is a good idea?
3. You want to allocate structures, so the `sizeof()` operands should be `xyz_t` and not `xyz_t *`; repeat for `abc_t`.

You should probably use:

```
int Lookup(const char *lookup, xyz_t **handle)
{
    ...
    *handle = (xyz_t *)malloc(sizeof(xyz_t));
    (*handle)->ab = (abc_t *)malloc(sizeof(abc_t));
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to check the result of `malloc()`.

There are those who will castigate you for using casts on `malloc()`.  I won't.  When I learned C (a long time ago, years before there was a C standard), on a machine where the `int *` value for an address was not the same bit pattern as the `char *` address for the same memory location, where `malloc()` had to be declared `char *malloc()` or all hell broke loose, the casts were necessary.  **But** — and this is the major issue that people are concerned about — it is crucial that you compile with compiler options such that if you invoke a function without a prototype in scope, you will get a compilation error, or a warning that you will pay attention to.  The concern is that if you do not have a declaration for `malloc()` in scope, you will get incorrect results from using the cast which the compiler would diagnose if you don't.

On the whole, though, I think you should separate your lookup code from your 'create `xyz_t`' code — your function is doing two jobs and it complicates the interface to your function.

```
xyz_t *Create_xyz(void);
int Lookup(const char *lookup, const xyz_t *handle);
```

Comment: Is there a way where I could still keep the handle as void * and typecast it to xyz_t in Lookup() ?

Answer (score 0):

While casting of a `void*` to any pointer type is correct, it is not necessary in C, and it is not recommended for `malloc` (e.g. see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) ).

Also, you should specify `sizeof(xyz_t)`, not `sieof(xyz_t*)`, otherwise you allocate memory enough only for pointer, not for the whole structure.

And of course you should assign a pointer to `handle`, not to `*handle`. And `handle` should be of proper pointer type (`xyz_t*`).

Oh, and if the question is about casting `handle` to `xyz_t*`, then you can do it like `((xyz_t*)handle)->ab`.

I'd recommend reading a book before playing with pointers like that.

Comment: Ok, when I try handle->ab , I get "error: request for member 'ab' in something not a structure or union", is it because of sizeof(xyz_t*)

Comment: That's because you `handle` is `void*`. Declare it as `xyz_t*`, as it is actually.

Comment: Probably it should be `xyz_t **` to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want handle to hold a valid address of a xyz_t struct after the function call. Then you need to change the function signature and contents like so:

```
int Lookup (char *lookup, xyz_t **handle) {  // double indirection here

    *handle = (xyz_t *)malloc(sizeof(xyz_t));
    (*handle)->ab = (abc_t *) malloc(sizeof(abc_t));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
xyz_t *myhandle;
char lookup;  
Lookup(&lookup, &mynandle);

// now you can use it
myhandle->index ...
```

You will need to free the memory as well...

```
free(myhandle->ab);
free(myhandle);
```

Comment: Is there a way where I could still keep the handle as void * and typecast it to xyz_t in Lookup() ?

Comment: What is the benefit, in your view, of keeping a `void *`?  It is as type-unsafe as hell!

Comment: because the handle that is passed in is a void pointer. So here is the thing, if I keep the function as you have suggested how do I send a void *handle to it.

Ex: I want to achieve something like this

`void *myhandle;`

`char lookup;`  

`Lookup(&lookup, &mynandle);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass void *, here is the solution

int Lookup (char *lookup, void *handle) {

```
handle = malloc(sizeof(xyz_t));
((xyz_t *)handle)->ab = (abc_t *) malloc(sizeof(abc_t));
//
```

}